# Replace String only if string is search (preg_replace multibyte)

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, multibyte

I have a problem. I want to replace certain strings only if they are exactly like I typed. So if there is a string with `5 Eur`he should only be replaced with e.g. `Steam 5 Euro`, if he stands alone and not if the string is like `How are you 5 Eur pls`.

With my actual code this is not possible... I use e.g.:

```
$string = str_replace('Apple Itunes 25 Euro Guthaben Prepaid De', 'Apple iTunes 25 Euro', $string)
```

Because here the string contains `25 Eur` this code is also adding some stuff:

```
$string = str_replace('25 Eur', 'Steam 25 Euro', $string);
```

But if I want to use `preg_replace(/\b25 Eur\b/i)` I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '�' in

So I have two questions:

1. How can I use an multibyte replace function?
2. How can I tell this function only to replace a certain string if he stands alone and not if he contains the searched string?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: I don't see unknown modifier, but anchor the pattern `/^25 Eur$/i`

Comment: This is just a snippet. My actual list is longer and contains chars like `�` - With `/^25 Eur$/i` it is only replacing if its a string and not stands alone? - ONLY IF ITS A STRING WITHOUT ANTHING?

Comment: unclear, what does mean *A STRING WITHOUT ANTHING*? because `/^25 Eur$/i` - is one case, `/\b25 Eur\b/i` - is another case

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: And why is that now being replaced with "True"? 

`$myTitle = "How are you?";

$string = mb_ereg_replace('/\bHow are you?\b/i', 'True', $myTitle);

echo $string;`

I get "How are you?"...

Comment: My comment above is working with `preg_replace` but not with `mb_ereg_replace`... Does anybody has an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This Should Work.

Search by:

```
^(25 Eur)$
```

Replace with:

```
Steam 25 Euro
```

Input:

```
Apple Itunes 25 Euro Guthaben Prepaid De', 'Apple iTunes 25 Euro
25 Eur
```

Output:

```
Apple Itunes 25 Euro Guthaben Prepaid De', 'Apple iTunes 25 Euro
Steam 25 Euro
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$re = '/^(25 Eur)$/m';
$str = 'Apple Itunes 25 Euro Guthaben Prepaid De\', \'Apple iTunes 25 Euro
25 Eur';
$subst = 'Steam 25 Euro';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/3DKEas/2