# How to cloak [ and ] in a mb_eregi_replace() regex?

Tags: php, regex, expression

I already googled and tried to cloak my string with `\`, `\\`and `/`, `//` but non of them worked.... My string is: `[XBOX XBOX Windows]` and I am using `mb_eregi_replace(...)`.

My question now is how can I cloak the `[` and `]` to tell the `mb_eregi_replace(...)` function that those both `[` and `]` chars pertain to the string?

My Code:

```
$string = "[XBOX XBOX Windows]";
echo mb_eregi_replace('\b[XBOX XBOX Windows]\b', 'XBOX Live 25 Euro', $string);
```

I put `\`, `\\`and `/`, `//` before the `[` and `]`.

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: No, does not work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, that along with *word boundaries* the search string also could be matched at the start and/or at the end of the string.
Use respective anchors `^`, `$`:

```
$string = "[XBOX XBOX Windows]";
echo mb_eregi_replace('(^|\b)\[XBOX XBOX Windows\](\b|$)', 'XBOX Live 25 Euro', $string);
// output: XBOX Live 25 Euro
```

Comment: Note that this will fail when there are spaces, commas, etc. directly before or after the `[` or `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you needed?

```
$string = "[XBOX XBOX Windows]";
echo mb_eregi_replace('\[XBOX XBOX Windows\]', 'XBOX Live 25 Euro', $string) . "\n"; // echoes 'XBOX Live 25 Euro'
```

Comment: Nearly. The output should be `XBOX Live 25 Euro` right. But I want to use `/bMySearchesWord/b` as well because it is saver.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape them with a backslash:

```
echo mb_eregi_replace('\b\[XBOX XBOX Windows\]\b', 'XBOX Live 25 Euro', $string);
```

**However**, your code does not work as you are putting word boundaries `\b` before and after the `[` and `]` characters and as the beginning, nor the end, nor both of these characters are word boundaries, you will match nothing.

An alternative to the word boundaries, would be something like the following, using an inverted characters class to match anything except a word character. But you'd have to adapt that to your requirements (beginning and end of the string for example):

```
echo mb_eregi_replace('[^\w]\[XBOX XBOX Windows\][^\w]', 'XBOX Live 25 Euro', $string);
```

Comment: But with word boundaries it is safer. Because I want only to replace and search for `[XBOX XBOX Windows]` and not if it is like `testtest[XBOX XBOX Windows]`

Comment: You asked that already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401062/replace-string-only-if-string-is-search-preg-replace-multibyte

Comment: @Jan Are you going to abandon this question as well?

Comment: This was another question. After this question I switched to `mb_eregi_replace(...)` and now I have this problem. So it is another question!

Comment: @Jan So you just left the one answer hanging with no feedback?  You can accept or delete or something.

Comment: I am new. How can I do that?